# Updating label contents from one view in another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm very new to iOS development and I know there have been questions like this asked, but I can't seem to pull out of those examples what I think I need.

I'm trying to teach this to myself by coding a very simple mortgage calculator.  I have two views, MortgageCalculatorViewController where the user enters the loan value, term and interest; and the ResultsViewController where this information is redisplayed, with the monthly payment, in labels.  My current issue is I can't seem to figure out how to relay the calculated monthly payment value to the ResultsViewController.

I named the segue showResultsSegue.

In MortgageCalculatorViewController:

```
#import "MortgageCalculatorViewController.h"
#import "ResultsViewController.h"

@interface MortgageCalculatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation MortgageCalculatorViewController

NSString *paymentText;

-(IBAction)calculateMonthlyPayment
{
    float rate = (self.interestRate.text.floatValue / 12) / 100;
    long term = self.termInYears.text.integerValue;
    float principle = self.loanAmount.text.floatValue;

    float termedRate = pow((1 + rate), term);
    float payment;

    payment = (principle * rate * termedRate) / (termedRate - 1);

    paymentText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", payment];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showResultsSegue"]){
        ResultsViewController *controller = (ResultsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.paymentLabel.text = paymentText;
    }
}

@end
```

And in ResultsViewController:

```
@interface ResultsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *loanAmountLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *termInYearsLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *interestRateLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *paymentLabel;

-(IBAction)close;

@end
```

I've guided this approach on the information I found in [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers), but I'm still seeing no change after the segue.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showResultsSegue"]){
        ResultsViewController *controller = (ResultsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.paymentLabel.text = paymentText;
    }
}
```

When preparing for a segue, the view has probably not been loaded, so `paymentLabel` is `nil`. Instead, declare a `paymentText` property on `ResultsViewController` and assign that value to `paymentLabel` in `viewDidLoad`.

New `prepareForSegue:`

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showResultsSegue"]){
        ResultsViewController *controller = (ResultsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.paymentText = paymentText;
    }
}
```

Implementation for `ResultsViewController`:

```
@interface ResultsViewController : UIViewController

@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *paymentText;

@end

@implementation ResultsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.paymentLabel.text = self.paymentText;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your `ResultsViewController` has not initialized it's view elements, including the `paymentLabel` yet. Try explicitly calling `view` before setting the label text like so:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showResultsSegue"]){
        ResultsViewController *controller = (ResultsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [controller view];
        controller.paymentLabel.text = paymentText;
    }
}
```

Calling `view` will cause the view controller to load it's view elements, hence letting you set the label's text properly.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest why to do this without using delegates, singletons or as mentioned above using the prepareForSegue, is using NSUserDefaults.

Save string:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:paymentText forKey:@"payment"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Read string:

```
NSString *readPaymentString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"payment"];
```

What you basically need to do here is to use the save code I provided in one view and the read code in the second view, simple.

I hope it makes sense.